# get a method to return json in C# and asp.net MVC 2 or 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop

i use JSon to return allot of results when building a website, but find myself writing a a lot of code like this:

```
 return Json((
                    from s in searchResults
                    select new { 
                      orderID = s.OrderID,
                      OrderRealID = s.OrderRealID,
                      OrderStatus = s.OrderStatus,
                      OrderDate = s.OrderDate,
                      OrderVenue = s.VenueName + " - " + s.VenueLocation + " (" + s.VenueNumber + ")",
                      OrderStatusText = s.StatusOrderValue
                    }
                ), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

what i would like to do is something like this:

```
 public string ResultsToJson<T>(hashtable fields){
                    from s in T
                    select new { 
                      // loop through hash table
                    } }
```

and then simply call this function with whatever IEnumerable results i have
my question is would i be on the right lines here, what would be the best possible way to 
do this as it makes no sense to be writing in MVC and OOP but to keep rewriting code to just FROM ? IN ?
all the time.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What types does your hashtable (`Dictionary<T,T>` since 2.0) hold? If it's a plain `Dictionary<string,string>` then you could write the JSON yourself fairly trivially.

If it has a set of types that have more types inside, all the way down to the leaf nodes then it will be worth looking at the [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) library instead, as it has far more advanced JSON capabilities than the standard .NET JSON serializer.

Comment: my hashtable will have a key (Field i will use) and a value of (Property in T)  thought of creating a string and returning the string and then running return Json(System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(reultsfromcode),JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

Comment: So the key will be a string, and the value can be any type?

Comment: yes thats right, but thats the problem not sure what the best way is to try and build this so that i can just say loop through a"collection" and get the results without being Dependant on properties and types

Comment: i have this  return (T)ModelObject.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName)

Comment: @minus4 the problem with that is it may return an object that has properties itself. As long as all your objects override ToString and you call that it should be ok though.

Comment: Uhm, maybe use .ToString() method on both key and value?

Comment: i finally wrote this return Json(oSerializer.Serialize(searchResults), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);   but that returns A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'XXX' i think this is because the object ViewSearchResults is a subsonic table and subsonic has loads of other properties etc hence the reason why i am at the moment doing it a ather long winded way round but having to re-invent the wheel  arghhhh complicated hmmmm

Comment: @minus4 I would ditch the JsonSerializer and use the JSON.NET, it will save you hours

Comment: yeah i think thats what im gonna go play with reflection is going to be too much and probably more confusing to other developers on my team i think the biggest hurdle here is the fact its subsonic classes and they come loaded with all sorts anyway chris thanks for all your brain storming much appreciated

Comment: chris S - that's the route i suggested too (newtonsoft json.net). i think it's for the best...

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at
[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).
The class will serialize data for you into a JSON  string

You could then use jQuery.parseJson(...) if you wish to consume in on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection to iterate through all properties. But use cache with it as it is painfully slow.

Comment: yes i think i would need reflection on looking i realised i wouldent be able to use the hash table to then work with reflection in order to get <T>.<Property>

Comment: Using reflection you can do ConvertToJSON(object o). No need to use strong typing then. Also you can get property name or create custom attributes to make it all convert as expected (for example [JsonName("Something")]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from one of my test (educational) projects:

```
public class OneTwoThree
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Should serialize the anonymous object
/// and deserialize it into a strong type.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     An MVC JSON result on the server can use anonymous objects that are serialized
///     into strong types on a rich client.
///
///     “Making use of your JSON data in Silverlight”
///     [http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/05/06/use-json-data-in-silverlight.aspx]
///
///     “ASP.NET MVC: Using dynamic type to test controller actions returning JsonResult”
///     [http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/24/asp-net-mvc-using-dynamic-type-to-test-controller-actions-returning-jsonresult.aspx]
///
///     “ASP.NET MVC – Unit Testing JsonResult Returning Anonymous Types”
///     [http://www.heartysoft.com/post/2010/05/25/ASPNET-MVC-Unit-Testing-JsonResult-Returning-Anonymous-Types.aspx]
///
///     “.NET 3.5: JSON Serialization using the DataContractJsonSerializer”
///     [http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx]
/// </remarks>
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldSerializeAnonymousObject()
{
    var data = new
    {
        One = "uno",
        Two = "dos",
        Three = "tres"
    };

    var result = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
    };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var actual = serializer.Serialize(result.Data);
    var expected = @"{""One"":""uno"",""Two"":""dos"",""Three"":""tres""}";
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    var clientSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OneTwoThree));

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(actual)))
    {
        var clientObject = clientSerializer.ReadObject(stream) as OneTwoThree;
        Assert.IsNotNull(clientObject);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Should serialize the generic dictionary
/// and deserialize it.
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldSerializeGenericDictionary()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("One", "uno");
    dictionary.Add("Two", "dos");
    dictionary.Add("Three", "tres");

    var result = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = dictionary,
        ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode
    };

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var actual = serializer.Serialize(result.Data);
    var expected = @"{""One"":""uno"",""Two"":""dos"",""Three"":""tres""}";
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    var clientSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(actual)))
    {
        var clientObject = clientSerializer.ReadObject(stream) as Dictionary<string, string>;
        Assert.IsNotNull(clientObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm curious, why not do this?

```
return Json(searchResults, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

That uses JavaScriptSerializer under the hood, which handles a fairly large range of types.  As long as you don't have any circular references, a simple collection of flat objects (per your example) shouldn't be a problem for the built-in serializer.

Comment: because it is subsonic classes and returns and error A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'XXX'  see my above comments on this earlier  thanks

Comment: That wasn't in your question.  You ought to update it to specify that, for people who read this in the future.  Don't want to send them off adding more complexity than is necessary in cases where the collection is serializable with the Json() helper.